# Adding value to columns based on string iteration in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Still no success with this, is there a way to bump it?

I have a Pandas dataframe of song lyrics containing the sequences of words *"know your name"* or *"know her name"* with the columns **artist**, **song**, **link**, **text**, and **opinion** (empty as of now). So far so good.
*NOW* I want to iterate through every row in **text** for the phrase *"i wanna know her name"* or *"i want to know her name"* and pass in "Wants to know name" on the same row under **opinion**. They have to be case insensitive. 
I've tried writing two functions:

```
def standpointification(df):
for text in df['text']:
    if 'wanna know your name' in text.lower() or 'want to know your name' in text.lower():
        df['Opinion'] = 'Wants to know name'
    elif  df['Opinion'] = "Doesn't want to know name"
```

That didn't work. It passes in "Doesn't want to know name" on all rows, and I know that's not true cause I checked manually.
So I tried str.contains instead:

```
def opinionnotification(df):
for text in df['text']:
    if str.contains("i wanna know your name", case=False) or str.contains("i want to know your name", case=False):
        df['Opinion'] = 'Wants to know name'
    else: df['Opinion'] = "Doesn't want to know name"
```

I'm obviously doing something terribly wrong here because it returns

> AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'contains'

First I'd be happy to just have this function work as described, but ultimately I would also like to add some more conditions along the lines of *"if the row in the text column contains "wanna know your name" but not "don't wanna know your name"*. Thankful for any pointers!
[sample of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4pcv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list1 = ['Hey baby baby oh yeah I wanna know your name', "What in the hell I don't wanna know your name baby girl", 'i wanna know your name']

df = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=['text'])
df['Opinion'] = pd.Series().astype('object')

def opinionnotification(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if 'i wanna know your name' in row['text'].lower():
            df.at[index, 'Opinion'] = 'Wants to know name'
        else:
            df.at[index, 'Opinion'] = "Doesn't want to know name"
    return df


print(opinionnotification(df))
```

Output:

```
                                                      text                    Opinion
0  Hey baby baby oh yeah I wanna know your name             Wants to know name       
1  What in the hell I don't wanna know your name baby girl  Doesn't want to know name
2  i wanna know your name                                   Wants to know name
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not change anything in the 'Opinion' column. Where is this code referring to looking in the 'text' column if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your df so I can recreate it?

Comment: Still no difference, I added a screenshot of the df for reference in my original post

Comment: Can you post a sample text where the result in the opinion cell is "wants to know name" and a sample text where the result is "Doesn't want to know name"?

Comment: "Hey baby baby oh yeah I wanna know your name" = Wants to know name
"What in the hell I don't wanna know your name baby girl" = Doesn't want to know name

Comment: I thought it was completely solved but for some reason it skips out on classifying many of the rows even though I change the sentence to be very specific.. It makes no sense. Thank you so much for all your effort

Comment: Happy to help! Can you give me an example of a row it skips?

Comment: I noticed the first index got "Doesn't want to know" when the phrase in the text goes "did not know your name". So to try it out I changed the first if statement to "did not know your name", and it still returned "Doesn't want to know". Maybe I could send you the jupyter notebook and csv files so you can have a first hand look?

Comment: https://github.com/blezzbeats/wannaknowyourname made a repository for it where Stage 2 is where I'm at right now! Hopefully it's not too messy